# What is this Kanji?

Tags: kanji, writing-identification

[image: This image]

What is this kanji between 今日は and って? I can't recognize, and a search by radical don't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

> 今日{きょう}は帰{かえ}って
>
> Kyou ha kaette

The radicals are [刀 (in the form 刂)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%88%80%E9%83%A8),   [彐](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%91%E9%83%A8) or [巾](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B7%BE%E9%83%A8).

Comment: The radical is usually given as `巾`, or sometimes as `刀` (in the form `刂`).  I just checked a bunch of dictionaries and I can't find any that list it under `彐`.  Which dictionaries do that?

Comment: @snailboat good question. It popped up as the main radical in my dictionary (even though I filtered by `刂`). Let me check what dictionary/database it got that from.

Comment: A dictionary I have doesn't list the radical of a kanji, but rather all parts under a "Radical(s)" section.  I'm not sure if that is what is happening here.

Comment: @snailboat Jim Breen's WWWJDIC does.